# Converting from group by output to separate columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have a grouped by pandas dataframe that looks like so:

```
id  type  count
 1   A     4
 1   B     5
 2   A     3
 3   C     0
 3   B     6
```

and I am hoping to get an output:

```
id A  B  C
1  4  5  0
2  3  0  0
3  0  0  6
```

I feel like there is a straightforward solution to this that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use pivot

```
df.pivot('id', 'type', 'count').fillna(0)
```

Comment: and then add `fillna(0)` - `df.pivot('id', 'type', 'count').fillna(0)`

Comment: Thanks - I knew there was a straightforward way to do this!